# firstOrCreate and join laravel how to use?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I join two tables with `firstOrCreate` method?
For example

```
MyModel::firstOrCreate(["user_id" => $user_id])
   ->join("theSecondTable", "theSecondTable.id", "=", "MyModelTable.item_id") ;
```

this way is not working I always get the first row of the first user

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DB::table('MyModelTable')
        ->join('theSecondTable', 'MyModelTable.item_id', '=', 'theSecondTable.id')
        ->firstOrCreate(array('user_id' => $user_id));
```